# How to get all records from server in Android if pagination is set using Volley request

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am fetching records from a server in my Android application using the Volley library. Pagination is done by the server so I am only able to get the limited 10 records from the server in my RecyclerView. How to send limit and offset in JSON request to get all records until the end if this is the URL?

```
next": "http://localhost:9500/api/restqueue/?limit=10&offset=10",
```

Comment: If your using `recycle view` based on the scroll position once 10 item reached next increment the `offset` value

Comment: can you please share the code